# Pandas Error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.boxplot(df[features])
plt.show()
```

I want boxplot but I am having this error -
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: what is features ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot long your dataframe first:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
features = ['sepal_length','petal_width']

sns.boxplot(x = "variable",y="value",data = df[features].melt())
```

[image]